# What is the better way to use context in Android MVVM pattern?

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm trying to use MVVM pattern in my Android project. I know that businesses logic should be put in Model. Now if i want to intent to another Activity after some processing, what is the better way to call `startActivty(intent)` or `startService(intent)`?

In Model or ViewModel or Activity?

If in Model or ViewModel it mean have to pass context to them, but i think it not follow the decoupling rule.

If in Activity, what is Activity role in MVVM??

Thank you.

Comment: I also have same confusion. Even if we apply validation checks in ViewModel and need to set error message from string.xml, we need context for that as well.